# JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, syntax

I call simple PHP function in my JS:

```
var text = document.createTextNode("<?php get_parts(); ?>");
```

Function returns some option tags from db.

```
var text = document.createTextNode
("
<option selected=\'selected\' value = '0'>vyber partii</option>
<option value="1">ramena</option><option value="2">prsa</option>
<option value="3">zada</option><option value="4">ruce</option>
<option value="5">bricho</option><option value="6">nohy</option>
");
```

When checked in console, it says: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, pointing to an argument of the second option tag. value="1" <------ here

Can anyone explain me, whats the matter? I don't see any syntax error.

Comment: You are mixing double quotes and single quotes in the output. Therefor the escaping of the characters doesn't complete.

Comment: Do you really want to show the HTML to the user? Or do you actually want to create `option` elements and add them to a select element?

Comment: I attach that text variable to the option element later in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You can't span lines like that without using a `\` prior to the newline. (The newlines won't be in the resulting string.)
2. Even if you could, you're using `"` within your quoted material, which you *also* need to escape (with a `\`). (Or use `'` around the overall string, since you're not using those within the content.)

So:

```
var text = document.createTextNode
("\
<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"0\">vyber partii</option>\
<option value=\"1\">ramena</option><option value=\"2\">prsa</option>\
<option value=\"3\">zada</option><option value=\"4\">ruce</option>\
<option value=\"5\">bricho</option><option value=\"6\">nohy</option>\
");
```

Note the `\` prior to the newlines, and prior to the embedded `"` characters.

I would probably not use newlines that way, it's fragile. I'd do something like this:

```
var text = document.createTextNode
('<option selected="selected" value="0">vyber partii</option>' +
 '<option value="1">ramena</option><option value="2">prsa</option>' +
 '<option value="3">zada</option><option value="4">ruce</option>' +
 '<option value="5">bricho</option><option value="6">nohy</option>'
);
```

---

Side note: I assume the reason you're creating a text node is that you want to output this text as-is; that is, without it being treated as markup. But if that's not the case, just be aware that that's what will happen (the `<option...></option>` stuff will actually be text within the text node, not option elements).

If you're trying to create actual option elements, that's usually best done with the `Option` constructor; you then use `add` on the `select` element's `options` pseudoarray to add them to it (you'd think it would be `push`, but it's not quite an array, and `add` is more reliable cross-browser):

```
var select = /*...get a reference to the select element...*/;
select.options.add(new Option("vyber partii", 0));
select.options[select.options.length - 1].selected = true;
select.options.add(new Option("ramena", 1);
select.options.add(new Option("prsa",   2);
select.options.add(new Option("zada",   3);
select.options.add(new Option("ruce",   4);
select.options.add(new Option("bricho", 5);
select.options.add(new Option("nohy",   6);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `<option value="1">` and others you have quotes.

You need to either escape every quote in the string, or use single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` back slashes to escape the `"` double quotes

```
var text = document.createTextNode
("
<option selected=\'selected\' value = '0'>vyber partii</option>
<option value=\"1\">ramena</option><option value=\"2\">prsa</option>
<option value=\"3\">zada</option><option value=\"4\">ruce</option>
<option value=\"5\">bricho</option><option value=\"6\">nohy</option>
");
```

**OR** use `'` single quotes

```
var text = document.createTextNode
("
<option selected='selected' value='0'>vyber partii</option>
<option value='1'>ramena</option><option value='2'>prsa</option>
<option value='3'>zada</option><option value='4'>ruce</option>
<option value='5'>bricho</option><option value='6'>nohy</option>
");
```

In Javascript, you cannot break a string literal into multiple lines like **above code samples**. You also need to escape it with back slash `\`.

**ERROR**

```
var s = "Hello 
         World";
```

**OK**

```
var s = "Hello\
         World";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :)

```
function get_parts(){

    $txt = "<option selected='selected' value = '0'>vyber partii</option>";
    $txt .= "<option value='1'>ramena</option>";
    $txt .= "<option value='2'>prsa</option>";
    $txt .= "<option value='3'>zada</option>";
    $txt .= "<option value='4'>ruce</option>";
    $txt .= "<option value='5'>bricho</option>";
    $txt .="<option value='6'>nohy</option>";
    return $txt;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = document.createTextNode("<?php echo get_parts(); ?>");
console.log(text.data);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must escape Quotes.

```
var text = document.createTextNode
("
<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"0\">vyber partii</option>
<option value=\"1\">ramena</option><option value=\"2\">prsa</option>
<option value=\"3\">zada</option><option value=\"4\">ruce</option>
<option value=\"5\">bricho</option><option value=\"6\">nohy</option>
");
```

Comment: Note that the newlines are also a problem.

Comment: thats right bro. But the code is only there that the questioner understands that. New Lines with ** \\ ** or set it to a single line.